# Configure Mocha to look for `.jsx`/`.es6` files

Tags: mocha.js, ecmascript-6, reactjs

Mocha can process JSX and ES2015 syntax with a help of Babel:

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-register
```

But when I try to run it over my test folder it can't find any tests. The reason is that the files there have `.jsx` extension and Mocha only looks for `.js`.

Is it possible to configure Mocha to look for `.jsx`/`.es6` files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mocha accepts globs so it is possible to do this at the command line:

```
mocha 'test/**/*.{es6,jsx}'
```

The quotes are so that the shell does not try to interpret it and mangle it in the process. It may actually work without them, but better safe than sorry...

So you can put the pattern in `test/mocha.opts` and Mocha will read it with every invocation. Just put this in the file:

```
test/**/*.{es6,jsx}
```

Or add it at the end of your `mocha.opts` file if you already have other options in there.

Comment: Awesome! Have I missed something from the docs or it isn't there?

Comment: The docs are obscure about this, I think. I don't recall seeing anything specifically about globs in the doc. And *think* the docs do not make explicit the idea of putting arguments other than switches (i.e. those that begin with `--`) in `mocha.opts`.  I've just checked and found that Mocha uses the [`glob` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) for glob processing. The documentation of that package should define the entire syntax.